# Make reference to C# code from multiple projects

Tags: c#, code-reuse

I have a `.cs` file full of C# code I keep reusing in multiple projects.

Right now I'm including it in these projects by copying and pasting the code into a new file in each project directory.  This is the ***wrong*** way to do it.

What's the ***right*** way to do it?

The right way should:

- keep the common code in only one place on my computer
- and keep the link fresh --- so when the common code changes, each project is aware of it, the next time I recompile that project.

Randomly guessing, I'd expect some sort of directive like `using mycode = C:\common\mycode.cs`, but I'm sure that's not the .NET way of doing things.

(I'm using C# 2010, .NET 4.0, and only compiling this code locally on one computer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a Class Library, add the file, build the project, and reference the DLL created from the build. Add the using statement to each file that will reference it. Also if it errors and the DLL is in the Project you and Right Click on the object -> Resolve and it will add the using for you.

Comment: I've done all that, but now I can't seem to make use of the functions from in the Class Library.  Do I need some sort of `using` directive?

Comment: @Joe Yes you need to add the reference to the project and then add the using in each file that references a class in the library. So at the top using [Namespace]. Also Visual Studio can resolve it by right-clicking if the DLL is in the Project.

Comment: And I also need to make the classes in the .dll public... *facepalm*

Comment: I have a question - I want to be able to deploy my programs as single .exe files - would I need to attach that .dll to the .exe then? I know I need to do that with 3rd party libraries, which I don't like to do. And which is why I kind of like the 'add as link' option below - in which the code will be automatically built into my app.

Answer (score 9):

Put the code into a separate class library project and reference that in your other projects.

Answer (score 9):

Or,

- Right-Click on the project in Solution explorer
- Select *Add Existing Item*
- Browse to the .cs file in another project, and Single-click to select the file
- Click the down-arrow button to the right of *Add* and select *Add as Link*

You now have one source file referenced by two projects but it has the namespace you gave it in the first project which might not be ideal.

The best way of organizing that is to as the two other answers have suggested, put common code in a class library so it has a namespace of MyClassLibrary rather than SomeOtherProject. It saves a larger dll being copied which doesn't matter much until you come to develop for something small like Windows Phone. Or change the namespace of common code to be Me.Common in all your apps - it doesn't really matter which one is the original, you can edit it from any project that references it.

Check that Source Control isn't a problem.

Comment: Had no idea "Add as Link" existed, thanks! Useful for small test projects where I couldn't care less about properly organizing my 10 lines of code into a separate class library project.

Comment: This was a very good quick fix solution, to start with. Later, maybe, either Class Library, or, Library with versions like in NPM/Nodejs modules (for if in Microservices architecture) will great.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app that automates adding a code as a link, handy for projects that reuse a lot of code and change a bit. It's at https://github.com/CADbloke/CodeLinker

or

Don't be afraid to edit XML .csproj files. For instance, this works ...

```xml
<Compile Include="$(Codez)\z.Libraries\diff-match-patch\DiffMatchPatch\**\*.cs"
Exclude="NotThisOne.cs;**\NotThisFolderWith\This*.cs">
<Link>Libs\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
</Compile>
```

...and will give you all the C# files from the source folder, and subfolders, as linked files in your destination project.

- `$(Codez)` is a Windows Environment Variable I use on my PCs.
- I also could have used `*.*` at the end instead of `*.cs`.
- This is one of those things Visual Studio might break on you, adding a file into the folder full of wildcard-linked files may break them out to separate entries. Or not. Depends on the wind.